# InvalidArgumentException Sorry only one package can be installed into the configured webroot

Tags: wordpress, composer-php

I'm trying to use `composer install` to install WordPress core and some plugins, using a custom directory structure. This does not seem to be a best practice going forward, but I need to install this locally as-is in order to test changing it on a server.

Currently, `composer install` is giving me an error.

> [InvalidArgumentException]
> Sorry only one package can be installed into the configured webroot.

I don't *think* this is trying to install more than one package in the webroot. I thought it was only installing WordPress core in the webroot.

Here's my composer.json:

```
    {
  "name": "mrengy/emandminbeantown",
  "description": "Em and M in Beantown Blog",

  "require": {
    "wordpress/wordpress": "5.8.*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/akismet": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/broken-link-checker": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/degradable-html5-audio-and-video": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/display-php-version": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/enable-media-replace": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/fitvids-for-wordpress": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/fix-image-rotation": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/jetpack": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/mailchimp-for-wp": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/postie": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/regenerate-thumbnails": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/simple-top-commenters": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/video-embed-thumbnail-generator": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/w3-total-cache": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/classic-editor": "*"
  },
  "repositories":[
      {
          "type":"composer",
          "url":"https://wpackagist.org"
      },
      {
        "type"    : "package",
        "package" : {
          "name"    : "wordpress/wordpress",
          "type"    : "webroot",
          "version" : "5.8",
          "dist"    : {
            "url"  : "https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/archive/5.8.zip",
            "type" : "zip"
          },
          "source" : {
            "url"       : "https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress",
            "type"      : "git",
            "reference" : "5.8"
          },
          "require" : {
            "fancyguy/webroot-installer" : "1.0.0"
          }
        }
      }
  ],
  "autoload": {
      "psr-0": {
          "Acme": "src/"
      }
  },
  "config"      : {
      "vendor-dir": "content/vendor",
      "allow-plugins": {
      "johnpbloch/wordpress-core-installer": true,
      "composer/installers": true,
      "fancyguy/webroot-installer": true
    }
  },
  "extra" : {
    "installer-paths": {
      "content/plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-plugin"],
      "content/themes/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-theme"]
    },
    "webroot-dir"     : "wp",
    "webroot-package" : "wordpress",
    "wordpress-install-dir": "wp"
  }
}
```

The weird thing is, I was able to run `composer install` with no errors on a very similar composer.json in another repo.

```
{
  "name": "mrengy/mike-eng.com",
  "description": "personal website",
  "require": {
    "johnpbloch/wordpress": "5.8.*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/akismet": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/broken-link-checker": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/email-address-encoder": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/enable-media-replace": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/image-rotation-fixer": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/jetpack": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/kimili-flash-embed": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/manual-image-crop": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/show-current-template": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/syntax-highlighter": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/wpaudio-mp3-player": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/wp-retina-2x": "*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "wpackagist-plugin/debug-bar": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/debug-bar-console": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/wordpress-importer": "*"
  },
  "repositories":[
      {
          "type":"composer",
          "url":"https://wpackagist.org"
      },
      {
        "type"    : "package",
        "package" : {
          "name"    : "wordpress",
          "type"    : "webroot",
          "version" : "5.8",
          "dist"    : {
            "url"  : "https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/archive/5.7.zip",
            "type" : "zip"
          },
          "source" : {
            "url"       : "https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress",
            "type"      : "git",
            "reference" : "5.8"
          },
          "require" : {
            "fancyguy/webroot-installer" : "1.0.0"
          }
        }
      }
  ],
  "autoload": {
      "psr-0": {
          "Acme": "src/"
      }
  },
  "config"      : {
      "vendor-dir": "content/vendor"
  },
  "extra" : {
    "installer-paths": {
      "content/plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-plugin"],
      "content/themes/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-theme"]
    },
    "webroot-dir"     : "wp",
    "webroot-package" : "wordpress",
    "wordpress-install-dir": "wp",
    "dropin-paths": {
      "content/languages/": ["vendor:koodimonni-language"],
      "content/languages/plugins/": ["vendor:koodimonni-plugin-language"],
      "content/languages/themes/": ["vendor:koodimonni-theme-language"]
    }
  }
}
```

I got the same error on Composer v 1.10.26 ([full terminal output](https://pastebin.com/rGhnGe4p)) and Composer v 2.2.7 ([full terminal output](https://pastebin.com/VdfMiWpF))

How do I fix this and `composer install` successfully?

Comment: Yeah, hasty at work ^^. Did the verbose flag shed some light? It should add a backtrace to the error message, I'm not entirely sure, but ***webroot*** somewhat created the impression on my end this might be related to a Plugin/Extension and this could be visible in such a trace. Disabling scripts and plugins on the command-line are another easy way to trouble-shoot if that is the case, just by disabling them (not suggesting it is your final solution, but may help to find the culprit), `composer --no-plugins install --no-scripts` that would be for both.

Comment: Ah and now seeing all those wpackagist packages, this really looks like at least an installer plugin for wordpress is involved. So if the error is gone disabling plugins and scripts, it would be good to know to reduce the surface.

Comment: @hakre I used the verbose flag and linked to the output in the original question. Not sure what to make of it.

Also I ran `composer --no-plugins install --no-scripts` and got no errors. Saw a bunch of lines of "installing [plugin name]" but it didn't seem to actually install anything. Maybe that's expected?

Comment: Yes thats expected because with no plugins there aren't any installers (which are plugins). The packages then just go into `vebdor/...`. The error look to come from the fancyguy webroot installer and it looks like it only wants one to go in there by the wording of the error message, but I have no experience with it, so just guessing here. But at least its clear this is due to this plugin installer, maybe that gives you hint enough to dig deeper? Perhaps disallow fancyguy/... plugin in the composer.json (but keep the others)?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up 2 different WordPress installation methods - `fancyguy/webroot-installer` and `johnpbloch/wordpress`.  Pick one of them and then do a clean install with `rm -rf vendor && composer update -v`.